# Capture specific environment variable from Linux sub-shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I am trying to figure out a way to run a shell script B from script A, set or export a variable in script B, and be able to store that value in script A after script B finishes and its sub-shell returns.

I'm not trying to source script B. I only want 1 specific variable. I can add stuff to script A, but I don't want any variables possibly set in script B to overwrite anything in script A besides what I am specifically trying to capture.

I'm sure there are some ugly ways, like writing out all the variables I care about in A to a file, source script B, then read everything back in from the file and restore the variables in A, besides the variable set in B that I want. I'm looking for a relatively clean and straightforward way, if one exists.

Comment: "I don't want any variables possibly set in script B to overwrite anything in script A besides what I am specifically trying to capture" -- variables set in script B (in a subshell) won't overwrite any variables in A. Child processes cannot write to their parent process's environment variables. You'll need to specifically capture them.

Comment: Exactly... that's what I want to do. I want to specifically capture them, like in the title of my question. My statement was intended to head off suggestions of sourcing script B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1376611/432690) is good, it should be your first choice, especially if your B script does one thing and does it well (see [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well)) and this "one thing" means "computing this particular variable value".

But what if the main purpose of B is to print something else? or even interact with the user? Passing *additional* data via stdout requires additional parsing of the retrieved result. If so, a totally independent channel of communication between B and A is highly desired. In your case one way communication is sufficient.

A temporary file is in fact quite good for it. But when you say

> ugly ways, like writing out all the variables I care about in A to a file, source script B, then read everything back in from the file and restore the variables in A, besides the variable set in B that I want

you're turning the situation upside down and it's indeed ugly. The right way is to use a file to pass this one desired variable only.

In A:

```
tmpf_foo=$(mktemp)
```

Then you call B with `"$tmpf_foo"` as a command line argument and refer to the file by `"$1"` in B (or by another number, depending on the design). This may not be convenient if B already parses its command line arguments.

An alternative way is to `export tmpf_foo` in A and refer to the file as `"$tmpf_foo"` in B.

If B is a general purpose tool that can be used not only from within A, it's good to check (in B) if the file exists, before you write to it (e.g. `if [ -f "$tmpf_foo" ]; then …`).

Anyway, in B you write your desired value to the file. E.g. the file content will be:

```
12345
```

After B successfully finishes, in A you retrieve the value like this:

```
specificvariable=$(<"$tmpf_foo")
```

(equivalent to `specificvariable=$(cat "$tmpf_foo")` but without `cat`; not portable though).

If you need to pass more than one variable from B to A, you may use multiple lines and read them (in A) with `read`. But if you don't know in advance which variable(s) should be altered (or if any at all), then make B create lines in the file so it looks like this:

```
specificvariable=12345
othervariable="xyz 0"
bar=baz
unset var1
```

After B successfully finishes, in A you source the file:

```
. "$tmpf_foo"
```

Note you may pass *any* command this way (in the above example `unset` is a command) and it will be executed from within A. For this reason you should be very careful while writing to the file from within B and you should make sure no other (rogue) process can inject strings to the file.

At the end (in A) you remove the temporary file with `rm "$tmpf_foo"`.

Comment: Oh I like this. Exporting a temp file fits my use case nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Write that specific variable to stdout, then in A:

```
specificvariable=$(/path/to/B.sh)
```

Comment: Upvoted, few notes though (mostly with inexperienced users in mind): (1) this runs `B.sh`, so you run the whole command instead of sole `B.sh`, not additionally. (2) This will capture the whole output from `B.sh`, so if the script writes more than the desired variable, the solution cannot be easily applied. // If you wish you can assimilate my remarks into the answer as your own (i.e. without mentioning my input); I think this would make the answer even better.

Comment: This is a good option, however not for my use case, since B.sh does potentially emit other output. But this is a good answer for other people who make come across this question. Thanks