# How to get the result of command substitution without using stdio and stderr?

Tags: bash

I have a user-provided bash script that creates a directory in some way and outputs its path. It can work in many ways, for example, it can clone a git repository, do some setting up, and then output the path. Something like this:

```
git clone ...repo --quiet && echo "...path"
```

I run it using command substitution, wrapping with `$(...)` and using the resulting path. Something like this:

```
path=$(...)
```

The command itself is user-provided, so it can be anything, I can't anticipate it will always be git clone.

It works well, but if the commands before the final `echo` outputs anything, it will mess up the result. I could redirect stdout to stderr for all preceding commands and only use stdout at the last step, but I feel it's a hack.

Is there any way to leave stdout and stderr to the caller's stdout and stderr, but have a separate stream for the result?

Comment: Having a "separate stream for the result" is exactly what stdout is (as distinct from stderr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will save the last line of output:

```
path=$(whatever | tail -n 1)
```

If you need all the output to be utilized in some way:

- use `tee` to print the output to the tty

  ```
  path=$(whatever | tee /dev/tty | tail -n 1)
  ```
- or to save it

  ```
  path=$(whatever | tee ./file | tail -n 1)
  ```
- or to process it (and print to the tty or a file, *not* to stdout which feeds the variable)

  ```
  path=$(whatever | tee >(grep foo | wc -c >/dev/tty) | tail -n 1)
  ```
- You can even send (fork) the output to many destinations:

  ```
  path=$(whatever | tee /dev/tty ./file /some/named/fifo >(tool1) | tail -n 1)
  ```

Obviously a newline within the echoed path will break the solution.

---

If you can modify the final `echo` command in the user-provided script then please see [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1376627/432690) for an approach that uses temporary files.

Comment: It works if I want it to go to the terminal, but what if the stdout is redirected somewhere? I have a test.sh: ```path=$((echo "doing something..." && echo "path") | tee /dev/tty | tail -1) && echo $path > result```
If I call it with ```./test.sh > log.txt```, it still outputs to the terminal. Is there any way to support this? I'd like to have both lines in the log.txt, and only the "path" in the result.

Comment: Thank you, that link was a good guidance, I decided to go on the tempfile approach. This is the script I came up with: ```function dosth () { echo "doing something..."; echo "path" >$1; }; result_tmp=$(mktemp); trap 'rm $result_tmp' EXIT; dosth $result_tmp; path=$(cat $result_tmp); echo path > result```