# exit from entr inside script

Tags: linux, bash, script, entr

After some googling, I found the [`entr`](https://eradman.com/entrproject/) utility to run a command on a file update. I can get it working, but unfortunately, I'm unable to exit from it.

The literature about it isn't much and quite vague for me. I'd need a behaviour, like

- detect file change
- run my command (setting a VAR in the caller script)
- exit

But not sure how to achive this. Calling `entr` seems to be an infinite loop, it's running endlessly.

It's rather strange I couldn't find any similar usecases.  (https://github.com/eradman/entr)

Should I start playing with the `inotifywait` from inotify-tools package?

Comment: Unclear : Do you want to exit `entr` after the first detected file-change, meaning run the command only once and exit `entr`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Kamil Maciorowski for the detailed answer.

Since I'm already dealing with a temp file, I wouldn't bother creating another temp file for `entr`'s subprocess to store it's value.

Altough `entr` seems to be a cool little tool, I went with `inotifywait`:

```
inotifywait -q -e close_write $buff_file_path |
while read -r filename event; do
    :
done
result=$(cat $buff_file_path)
```

This will exit when an event occures. I'm basically just monitoring the file, and only reading it when it updated.

My initial description of the problem / desired result is a bit shady, I'll have to work on writing decent questions.

Credit goes to the kind people in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes) thread.

Answer (score 0):

#### Formal note

Your explicit question is:

> Should I start playing with the `inotifywait` from inotify-tools package?

I cannot answer this. Answers to "should I?" are usually opinion-based anyway. I think the implicit question is "how can I exit from `entr` inside a script?". This is the question answered below.

---

#### Solution

The following command:

```
entr -p sh -c 'kill -s INT "$PPID"; actual command(s)'
```

will (upon being triggered) make `entr` spawn a shell that will kill its parent (i.e. `entr`) and then execute `actual command(s)`.

---

#### Notes

- Without `-p` `entr` would execute `sh` right away and be killed right away. You need `-p`. From `man 1 entr`:

  > `-p`    Postpone the first execution of the utility until a file is modified.
- `entr` takes a command to be executed (executable + arguments) as its own separate arguments. A syntax like:

  ```
  entr echo "$var"
  ```

  is totally fine. However for `sh -c` you pass *shell code*, a string that will be *interpreted* by the shell. Our `actual command(s)` will be parsed by the shell. If you need the outer shell to expand anything and pass to the inner shell, do not do this:

  ```
  entr -p sh -c 'kill -s INT "$PPID";'" echo $var"
  ```

  nor anything like it. To do it safely, make the shell code (the option-argument for `sh -c`) *static* and use positional arguments to pass variable values. Example:

  ```
  entr -p sh -c 'kill -s INT "$PPID"; echo "$1"' sh "$var"
  ```

  Here, even if `$var` expands to `; rogue code`, `'; rogue code`, `'$(rogue code)` or anything else, it won't be able to break the actual shell code.

  <sup>(Compare ["never embed `{}` in the shell code"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618), it's basically the same issue.)</sup>
- Your goal is "setting a VAR in the caller script". Without a debugger only the shell interpreting the script can change its its own variables. A command run under `entr` cannot do this. You can capture its output or make it write to a file and then let the shell read the file. See answers to this question: [*Capture specific environment variable from Linux sub-shell*](https://superuser.com/q/1376604/432690).